# d3 filling an area with a gradient

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gradient

I'm wanting to fill the area of this line chart with a gradient, so that the bottom of the gradient is transparent, and the top of the area fill is black. Is this possible?

All my google searches are bring up charts like: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4433087 - I don't want the gradient to be based on the values, in this example I'd want red across the top of the area, not just when a value reaches that %.

```js
var entries = [{"date":"2016-01-06","value":15},{"date":"2015-11-17","value":15.4},{"date":"2015-11-11","value":16.5},{"date":"2015-09-24","value":15.1},{"date":"2015-08-22","value":15},{"date":"2015-08-12","value":15},{"date":"2015-07-30","value":14.6},{"date":"2015-07-19","value":14.8},{"date":"2015-07-18","value":14.9},{"date":"2015-07-12","value":14.9},{"date":"2015-07-08","value":14.9},{"date":"2015-06-29","value":14.3},{"date":"2015-06-21","value":14.5},{"date":"2015-06-18","value":14.7},{"date":"2015-06-09","value":15},{"date":"2015-06-08","value":14.1},{"date":"2014-12-06","value":13.4},{"date":"2014-09-10","value":13.1},{"date":"2014-08-01","value":14.2},{"date":"2014-07-07","value":15},{"date":"2014-05-31","value":14},{"date":"2014-05-24","value":15},{"date":"2014-05-14","value":15},{"date":"2014-05-13","value":14},{"date":"2014-05-08","value":14.5},{"date":"2014-05-02","value":15}];

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
 overlayW = $('.chart').innerWidth(),
 overlayH = $('.chart').innerHeight(),
 width = overlayW,
 height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom,

 parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse,
 bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
 formatValue = d3.format(",.2f");

var x = d3.time.scale()
 .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x)
 .tickSize(0)
 .tickValues(x.domain())

 .orient("bottom")
 .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .tickSize(0)
 .ticks(5)
 .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
 .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
 .y0(height)
 .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var svg = d3.select(".drawn").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-15,30)");

enter(entries);






function enter(data) {

 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.value = +d.value;
 });

 data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.date - b.date;
 });

  x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));
  //y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));
  var e = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
  



  svg.append("path")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("class", "area")
   .attr("d", area);





  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
   .call(yAxis);



}
```

```css
.chart {display:block;background:#4BAC4E;height:250px;width:600px;}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

text {
  font: 400 11px mono;
  letter-spacing: .3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.domain {
  display: none;
}

.area {
  fill: black;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
  <div class="drawn"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5kesyqu0/3/

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this making a linear gradient like this:

```
//make defs and add the linear gradient
var lg = svgmain.append("defs").append("linearGradient")
.attr("id", "mygrad")//id of the gradient
.attr("x1", "0%")
.attr("x2", "0%")
.attr("y1", "0%")
.attr("y2", "100%")//since its a vertical linear gradient 
;
lg.append("stop")
.attr("offset", "0%")
.style("stop-color", "red")//end in red
.style("stop-opacity", 1)

lg.append("stop")
.attr("offset", "100%")
.style("stop-color", "blue")//start in blue
.style("stop-opacity", 1)
```

Then add this gradient to the fill of your path.

```
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area)
        .style("fill", "url(#mygrad)");//id of the gradient for fill
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/b32o2z03/).

Another example as per your [requirement](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/Lzzd5x5w/) (*So that the bottom of the gradient is transparent, and the top of the area fill is red*).

Comment: Thanks but this isn't what I'm wanting. I need the top of the line to be where the red begins, not the top of the chart.

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but it gave me some ideas. Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

I might be late to this party, but exactly the same result I wanted to accomplish recently. While browsing internet I found this SO question and decided to post my own answer. Looks like no one else ever posted this solution yet. So, here goes:

```
let svgDefs = svg.append('defs');    

let filterBlur = svgDefs
    .append("filter")
    .attr('id', 'blur')
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 20);
    
let mask = svgDefs
    .append("mask")
    .attr('id', 'mask')
    .datum(data)
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); }));

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("stroke", "#274EF6")
    .attr("stroke-width", 15)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("filter", "url(#blur)")
    .attr("mask", "url(#mask)")
    .attr("class", "line-blur")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.value);
        }));
```

Basic idea is not to use area chart, instead use line chart with pretty wide line-width. Then, apply blur effect to it and then mask property, where path of the mask will be created by that area, which we discarded at first step. Hope it is helpful[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/RomanTourdyiev/dzcfsh1x/5/